# Nginx Session-Binding-Proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

I've been trying to harden a website against attacks involving Session Hijacking. The site runs with Nginx in front of an node.js app. As one of the countermeasures, the goal is to configure Nginx to bind application session ID's to SSL sessions. For this, I use the the following 3rd party module: https://github.com/wburgers/Session-Binding-Proxy, which implements the concept as described in the the following [paper](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~rverdult/Prevent_Session_Hijacking_by_Binding_the_Session_to_the_Cryptographic_Network_Credentials-NORDSEC_2013.pdf).

I successfully rebuilt Nginx with the module, but I'm having a very hard time to get it to work correctly (or even consistently, for that matter). No matter what I try, the proxy either:

1) A checksum mismatch:

```
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 ssl_session_master_key: 25a913d0524eb78d8433fdd5f5cf930a9a948ce09f5bfd8d
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 Session Binding Proxy encryption/decryption key: 80F426773F639A33C3279B55BDE9842D3767844DA026AEFF523C08DA03257A00
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 Session Binding Proxy Handler searching for: connect.sid
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 Session Binding Proxy Handler in string: __insp_wid=1037948077; __insp_nv=true; __insp_ref=d; __insp_norec_sess=true; _ga=GA1.2.999148523.1418831731; __insp_slim=1418846762624; connect.sid=s%3AMnIX0bsYtYJV7LSIYPrf53S1LMQnWoo2.HpVHL9F3tQ%2BlawYAE49gmE%2FIz3wUjJhd0Fh7QgBQOTw
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 Encrypted cookie value: H
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [info] 3113#0: *1 Session Binding Proxy: SHA256 checksum mismatch., client: 82.173.175.112, server: www.somehost.com, request: "GET /api/init?timestamp=1418847452710 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.somehost.com", referrer: "https://www.somehost.com/"
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 ssl_session_master_key: 25a913d0524eb78d8433fdd5f5cf930a9a948ce09f5bfd8d
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 Session Binding Proxy Filter IV: F66F734D7C905BEE
2014/12/17 21:17:32 [debug] 3113#0: *1 Session Binding Proxy encryption/decryption key: 80F426773F639A33C3279B55BDE9842D3767844DA026AEFF523C08DA03257A00
```

2) Memory allocation errors in the log, combined with Nginx workers crashing:

```
2014/12/17 12:55:05 [emerg] 32348#0: *51 malloc(9837586053127471180) failed (12: Cannot allocate memory), client: 62.140.137.158, server: www.somehost.com, request: "GET /api/timeline/2014-12-17 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.somehost.com"
2014/12/17 12:55:05 [emerg] 32348#0: *52 malloc(7770600577343422540) failed (12: Cannot allocate memory), client: 62.140.137.158, server: www.somehost.com, request: "GET /api/timeline/2014-12-17 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.somehost.com"
2014/12/17 12:55:05 [emerg] 32348#0: *53 malloc(12574651495842054220) failed (12: Cannot allocate memory), client: 62.140.137.158, server: www.somehost.com, request: "GET /api/timeline/2014-12-17 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.somehost.com"
2014/12/17 12:55:06 [alert] 32119#0: worker process 32348 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
```

3) Inconsistent behaviour of the webapp itself. This is fairly obvious, considering the errors mentioned above. But, also with a much simpler website than the actual application I can't seem to get the module working correctly.

4) The Session-Binding-Proxy has an option to explicitly set the 'session_binding_proxy_key'. When it is omitted, the module generates a key on startup of Nginx as it is supposed to. When explicitly setting the key to an invalid value, starting Nginx gives an error and refuses to start (as expected). However, when setting the key to a valid key, the module doesn't seem to honor the setting and still uses a generated key.

Needless to say, without the Session-Binding-Proxy everything works as expected. But however I configure the SBP settings, it doesn't seem to work.
Does anybody have a clue what could be wrong? Has anyone got the Session-Binding-Proxy running as expected? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you try to clear the cookies in the browser when using SBP?
SBP cookies are encrypted and HMACed. If you have cookies from a session before you start using SBP, these cookies are not valid for the SBP module.
If a cookie is invalid, it is sent to the application server without modification. The application server should log out the session and start a new one.

2) Those malloc errors are not really helpful. I'll try to reproduce an invalid cookie and see if I get them as well. Maybe I can improve SBP on this point.

3) What kind of inconsistent behaviour? Does the app log you out randomly?

4) The specified key is respected, but there was no output in the logs or on start-up. Please check the latest version. (Updated today after comments from your colleague?) The (debug) output shows the key you set in the config (or the random key if you didn't set the sbp_key directive.

Hope this helps.
If you have any other questions, feel free to shoot in issues at github, because I don't check here often.